# Rails Admin: Usage of `has_and_belongs_to_many` causes huge memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, rails-admin

Edit:
Turns out that the described case is not the root cause of the memory consumption. Therefore I'll close this one down. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I'm using rails_admin to manage the data in the database.
I've got an n-to-m relationship between two tables that cause the rails_admin application to eat up to 150MB additional memory for each unique `n` I want to edit.

Needless to say, this is bad and feels like I'm doing something wrong.

This is my branch-table:

```rb
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plant_state_bit_alarm,
                          class_name: 'Alarm',
                          join_table: :plant_state_bit_alarms
  # ...
  edit do
    # this causes the memory "hogging" - If I don't filter, it will hog anyway
    field :plant_state_bit_alarm do
      associated_collection_scope do
        branch = bindings[:object]
        Proc.new { |scope| scope = scope.where(branch_id: branch.id) if branch.present? }
      end
    end
  end
```

The alarm-table:

```rb
class Alarm < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

And the intermediate table:

```rb
class PlantStateBitAlarm < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :alarm
  belongs_to :branch

  rails_admin do
    visible false
  end
end
```

I'm having only two branches in my database but many alarms in my database (roughly 35k for each branch). When I want to edit either branch, the memory of the application hit up to 700 MB and never reduces itself, causing production server to kill my application with the OOM killer.

There's a very small memory limit right now (256MB) which exceeds the moment I want to edit one of these branches. I can extend it but I fear that it will be an issue for the future me so I rather get it fixed right now.

I'm open for suggestions to handle this but my knowledge of rails_admin only covers the wiki pages and this appears to be something weirder. I'm mostly worried that the memory is not freed at all.

Some version information:

- Ruby: 2.6.3
- Rails: 5.0.7.2
- rails_admin: 1.4.2

(Updating rails and rails_admin didn't show any change)

Answer (score 1):

I think rails is loading all the Alarms thanks to the class_name: 'Alarm' argument. Usually if you wanted this setup you need to setup the association like this:

```
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :alarms, join_table: :plant_state_bit_alarms
end
```

This way you don't even need the PlantStateBitAlarm model, unless you want special logic in that association.

And then you can add the alarms field to the Branch Rails Admin config and it will let you add alarms and create the association record automatically.

Comment: Mh... no, it still loads all the alarms. But this time I can not select them because I had to remove the `associated_collection_scope` bit.

Comment: Turns out that there is another issue unrelated to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` which suddenly triggered bigger memory consumption. I'll have to create another question but thats for your help nontheless.